# Else required if "if" ends with return?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

When in JavaScript there's a function that consists of an if statement and the if-statement ultimately ends in a return statement, is it *required* to add an `else` statement as well? An example to illustrate:

```js
function is_fruit(boolean) {
    var banana = boolean,
        str = "I am fruit.";

    if (banana) return str;
    return str.replace("fruit","Groot");
}

alert(is_fruit(false));
```

In the above example we first check if the boolean is set to true. If it is, we simply return the var `str` (and considering we are using `return`, that's the end of the function all together!). However, when banana isn't true, we skip the if-statement and execute the rest of the function - in this case another return function.

In practice, this can be re-written as:

```js
function is_fruit(boolean) {
    var banana = boolean,
        str = "I am fruit.";

    if (banana) return str;
    else return str.replace("fruit","Groot");
}

alert(is_fruit(true));
```

I prefer the second method because it's simply more intuitive and cleaner in my opinion. However, are there any other differences that need to be considered? E.g. is the first one faster (on a large scale)? Or is there no difference because JS executes synchronously? And so on.

Comment: It's not required to have an `else` statement even if the `if` statement has a return value, it's not even a best practice in my opinion, but many linters will tell you that the function *"does not always return a value"* as a warning.

Comment: *"This question might be close to opinion"* Yes, opinion based questions are discouraged. | *"is the first one faster (on a large scale)? "* I think you can answer that for yourself.

Comment: no it is not required to add an else. because the function will end at the first return that it encounter.

Comment: I would probably do `return banana ? str : str.replace("fruit","Groot");`

Comment: Oh man -- all those downvotes. And I thought I had a nice 'n' funny example. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The `else` is not required (as long as there's no way the function can terminate without hitting any `return` statement).

Having the `return` statement only in the `if` is actually pretty common, and even recommended by several coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the downvotes (I didn't downvote you!) - it's probably because opinion-based questions like this aren't favored here.

That said, my preference is to not use `else` in code like this. But even more, for a case where you're returning one value or another right away, I prefer the conditional expression that adeneo suggests. You can easily format it nicely too. For a simple case like this, a one-liner is fine, but if the code were a little more complex you could do this:

```
return banana ?
    str :
    str.replace( "fruit", "Groot" );
```

(I would have made this a comment instead of an answer, but multiline formatting doesn't work in comments.)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works actually. How come that even though `return` precedes `banana`, it is `str` (or its replacement) that are actually returned?

Comment: The `?` and `:` make a [conditional expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), a very useful thing to learn about.